# QQml_colorProvider: no color provider has been set

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have strange qml error in my project,

```
Warning: QQml_colorProvider: no color provider has been set! 
"qrc:/gui/FirstPage.qml:5 Type GuiPage unavailable
qrc:/gui/GuiPage.qml:4 Invalid property assignment: color expected
```

Here is my GuiPage.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    color:"transparent"
    implicitWidth: 380
    implicitHeight:  350
    property string pageName: "sample"
    property bool active : false
    readonly  property int firstPage: 1
    readonly  property int lastPage: 2
    readonly property int normalPage : 3
    property int pageType : firstPage
    signal pageActivate
    signal pageClose

    property bool hasBlockers: false

    property int pageId: 0
    property QtObject fontLoader:  FontLoader{
        source: "font/Cuprum-Regular.ttf"
    }
}
```

I used last Qt from git stable branch, statically builded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this problem, need to put a small patch on the Qt5 (Qt 5.1.1 version still requires that)

```
--- qtdeclarative/src/quick/qtquick2.cpp    2013-06-15 17:41:23.000000000 +0200
+++ qtdeclarative/src/quick/qtquick2.cpp    2013-07-01 15:12:23.414228504 +0200
@@ -39,6 +39,8 @@
 **
 ****************************************************************************/

+#include "util/qquickglobal.cpp"
+
 #include "qtquick2_p.h"
 #include <private/qqmlengine_p.h>
 #include <private/qquickutilmodule_p.h>
```

This issue is described in more detail here: [QTBUG-28357](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28357)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention that I have the same issue and that issue is gone after "apt install qt5-quick-demos" on Ubuntu 22.04.

There's bunch of plugins installed:

```
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-window2 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [26,3 kB]
Get:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick2 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [33,7 kB]
Get:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects amd64 5.15.3-1 [74,3 kB]
Get:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtqml amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [17,2 kB]
Get:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtqml-models2 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [18,0 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-layouts amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [56,0 kB]
Get:7 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-controls amd64 5.15.3-1 [577 kB]
Get:8 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libqt5xmlpatterns5 amd64 5.15.3-1 [901 kB]
Get:9 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [36,1 kB]
Get:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qt-labs-settings amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [26,5 kB]
Get:11 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-templates2 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [77,0 kB]
Get:12 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-controls2 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [935 kB]
Get:13 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets amd64 5.15.3-1 [49,8 kB]
Get:14 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs amd64 5.15.3-1 [132 kB]
Get:15 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-particles2 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-1 [19,3 kB]
Get:16 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel amd64 5.15.3-1 [37,3 kB]
Get:17 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 qt5-quick-demos amd64 5.15.3-1 [2 191 kB]
```

Some qml plugin must be missing or misconfigured, I've stopped tracking that issue after that fix.